# PyQGIS Use of external script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, standalone

I have downloaded script "Save features filtered by expression" in Processing toolbox ->  Scripts (It is saved in `/home/user/.QGIS/processing`) and I would like to call this script in standalone PyQGIS script. It works nice if used in normal Ubuntu with QGIS.

I call it with this:

```
# select by attribute (select water)
input_file=sys.argv[1]
output_file=sys.argv[2]
expression='DN=1'
general.runalg("script:Savefeaturesbyfilteredexpression",input_file,expression,output_file)
```

But when I try use it with my Docker Image it is not working anymore because that directory does not exist. If I have the file downloaded where I should script copy to and how to call it?

I am asking in general how to use external script. Other processing tools (grass, gdal) works in my Docker Image, but this script has a error: `Algorithm not found`.

EDIT:
I have copied the script (in docker image) to the same location as in Ubuntu. But it is still not working. `Error: Algorithm is not found`.

Is there a default folder to put external script and PyQGIS will automatically find it there and will use it or script can be anywhere and I am supposed call script by some function to make it working?

Comment: Why not use docker ADD (copy script dir to container) https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add

Comment: Wich docker image are you using ?

Comment: I created my own. I use ubuntu 16.04 and QGIS 2.18. But I would like to know some general answer about using external python scripts in pyQGIS not just in docker.

Comment: You say it works fine without the docker image. The script is missing in your container, so this explains why it is not working. So I don't see the problem

Comment: I have copied it to the /usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/script  but that is not working. I have the script in my image but I do not know where should it be and how to call it. Can it be anywhere and I am supposed to add it by some function to the script or is there default place where pyqgis look for the script...or what is the best practise to work with external python scripts in pyqgis. I will try to copy it to the folder /home/.qgis2/processing/scripts but It seem unusual to me if this folder structure is not created at all in default. It just doesn seem as normal place to put it.

Comment: @julsbreakdown I have created same location as in Ubuntu with script, but there is same error.

Comment: And when you create a custom script and do save as => you should see the path to processing scripts

Comment: Do you acess to the python console within Qgis ? try to get the default folder of processing/script_folder by `s=QSettings()` and then `s.value(u'Processing/Configuration/SCRIPTS_FOLDER')` It whould tells you where Qgis goes to get scripts.

Comment: I do not acess python within QGIS. I work with standalone pyqgis script on command line without GUI. Isn't there some option to "load" script or set a path to the script ?

Comment: import sys ; sys.modules['processing'] or seems that in your case general

Comment: This is the result of sys.modules['processing'] -> <module 'processing' from '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/__init__.py'> and there was error with general.

Comment: So does /usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/script/ exist? If so your script should be here. I have qgis running on docker and I don't have this issue =(

Comment: It is there already. I really don't understand where is the problem. Same error all the time. I will try some other way to select and save features from vector layer maybe.